# Incomprehensible issue in a loop (C on Clion)

Tags: c

I'm learning C in my school for 2 months and I have to make a Halma's Game in the console, so I'm a newbie for now.
I use Clion and CodeBlock but I prefer Clion for his internal console.
The game work pretty good, but I've got 2 weird issues that I can't fix by myself:
- My loop is presumed to stop with the scanf,but it doesnt.
("saut" variable).
It work only in the 2nd(or more) passage in the loop.
-The variable "h" increment during the loop (in order to ignore the next condition when you are out the loop), but the program always get in.
I don't know why..

Check my code:
[MY CODE (IN FRENCH DON'T WORRY ABOUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1I7V.png)

Thanks for your help.
Robin.

Comment: Please don't post images of text, especially links to images of text. Instead copy-paste the text, as is, into the question body and format it properly. Please  [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Are you sure that saut is equal one before you get to while(saut == 1) ? Maybe you want do while there instead?

Comment: Saut is equal one yes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On some platforms (especially Windows and Linux) you can use fflush(stdin);:

Do modify your code like :-

```
while(saut==1)
...
....

scanf("%d",&saut);
fflush(stdin);
}
fflush(stdin);
```

these is another trick to solve this issue :-

It goes into an infinite loop because scanf() will not consumed the input token if match fails. scanf() will try to match the same input again and again. you need to flush the stdin.

if (!scanf("%d", &sale.m_price)) fflush(stdin)

Comment: I put your code (The first one) in mine but the problem of the loop still here. Maybe I've to change my code and rewrite it ?

Comment: try this if (!scanf("%d", &saut)) fflush(stdin);

Comment: It work now ! Thanks a lot ! the program stop after the end of the loop and don't get out the function (void).

Comment: Why I got down voting?

Comment: @SumitGemini probably because you've answered a terrible question

Comment: I don't know why, I can't vote because I have less than 15 reputations :/

Comment: Maybe because your anwer is missleading at best. `fflush`ing an input stream invokes undefined behaviour. It is a strict don't.

Comment: @RobinLbt I think Olaf is right, using fflush is risky. Therefore I modified above code " if (scanf("%d", &number) == 0) {   break;   } ". Hope it will work for you. Thanks Olaf to correct me.